# Select the available item serial numbers that can be assigned against order quantities required

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table called AvailableSerialNumbers, below is sample data.

| ItemCode | SerialNumber | AvailableQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | S10001 | 1 |
| P001 | S10002 | 1 |
| P002 | T20001 | 1 |
| P002 | T20002 | 1 |
| P002 | T20003 | 1 |
| P002 | T20004 | 1 |

Table called Orders, below is sample data.

| DocNum | OrderDate | ItemCode | RequiredQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 421 | 2023-03-01 | P001 | 1 |
| 422 | 2023-03-02 | P001 | 2 |
| 423 | 2023-03-03 | P002 | 3 |
| 424 | 2023-03-04 | P002 | 1 |
| 425 | 2023-03-05 | P002 | 2 |

Below is SQL to create the sample tables and data.

```
CREATE TABLE AvailableSerialNumbers 
(
    ItemCode nvarchar(100),
    SerialNumber nvarchar(255),
    AvailableQuantity numeric(8,2),
);

INSERT INTO AvailableSerialNumbers (ItemCode, SerialNumber, AvailableQuantity)
VALUES 
    ('P001', 'S10001', 1),
    ('P001', 'S10002', 1),
    ('P002', 'T20001', 1),
    ('P002', 'T20002', 1),
    ('P002', 'T20003', 1),
    ('P002', 'T20004', 1);


CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    DocNum int,
    OrderDate datetime,
    ItemCode nvarchar(100),
    RequiredQuantity numeric(8,2),
);

INSERT INTO Orders (DocNum, OrderDate, ItemCode, RequiredQuantity)
VALUES 
    (421, '2023-03-01', 'P001', 1),
    (422, '2023-03-02', 'P001', 2),
    (423, '2023-03-03', 'P002', 3),
    (424, '2023-03-04', 'P002', 1),
    (425, '2023-03-05', 'P002', 2);
```

Require a SQL Server query to output the list of available serial numbers (AvailableSerialNumbers table) and assign each row with a DocNum from the Orders table. Serial number row should only have a DocNum assigned if it's related to the same ItemCode and where the RequiredQuantity hasn't been exceeded from the Order having previous serial number rows assigned. Orders with the oldest OrderDate would be assigned first.

Expected output below based on sample data.

| ItemCode | SerialNumber | DocNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | S10001 | 421 |
| P001 | S10002 | 422 |
| P002 | T20001 | 423 |
| P002 | T20002 | 423 |
| P002 | T20003 | 423 |
| P002 | T20004 | 424 |

Comment: Please show what you have tried, what issues you've faced.

Comment: That was a very well written question, up until the point where there you forgot to add your attempt.

Comment: I think credit for the write-up might belong to the instructor, who may also expect students to at least try to do their own homework.

Comment: Good call @TN... I didn't pick that

Comment: See [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Comment: I will give you a few hints. Take a look at using the `GENERATE_SERIES()` function to enumerate `order` rows based on `RequiredQuantity`. The same can be done with `AvailableSerialNumbers` and `AvailableQuantity`. You can then look at the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)` to assign sequence numbers to each available and required item. Then what remains is matching the two up.

Comment: Compare running totals of available&required quantities(keep as many available units as required and vice versa): `select av.ItemCode, av.SerialNumber, o.DocNum
from (select sum(RequiredQuantity) over(partition by ItemCode order by OrderDate rows unbounded preceding) as rqrt, * from Orders) as o
join (select sum(AvailableQuantity) over(partition by ItemCode order by SerialNumber) as avrt, * from AvailableSerialNumbers) as av
on o.ItemCode = av.ItemCode and o.rqrt-o.RequiredQuantity < av.avrt and av.avrt - av.AvailableQuantity < o.rqrt`